# Android for Dummies code error

Tags: java, android

In *Android app Development for Dummies* and I am getting an error after the last bit of code.

> The method `setListAdapter(ArrayAdapter<String>)` is undefined for the type `ReminderListActivity`

The code is as follows:

```
package com.dummies.android.taskreminder;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

public class ReminderListActivity extends Activity {
  /** Called when the activity is first created. */
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.reminder_list);

    String[] items = new String[] { "Foo", "Bar", "Fizz", "Bin"};
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter =
      new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.reminder_row, R.id.text1, items);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like [`Activity`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) doesn't have `setListAdapter()` but its subclass [`ListActivity`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html) does.  Maybe you want

```
public class ReminderListActivity extends ListActivity {
```

instead?  This should work fine:

```
package com.dummies.android.taskreminder;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

public class ReminderListActivity extends ListActivity {
  /** Called when the activity is first created. */
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.reminder_list);

    String[] items = new String[] { "Foo", "Bar", "Fizz", "Bin"};
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter =
      new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.reminder_row, R.id.text1, items);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
  }
}
```

Comment: I still think my answer was better :P

Comment: It was a good, if symmetric, rivalry.  (Do I win on grounds I don't even own an android device, nor have I ever written any android code?)

Answer (score 1):

`Activity` doesn't define the method `setListAdapter()`. I think you want to extend `ListActivity` instead:

```
public class ReminderListActivity extends ListActivity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.reminder_list);

        String[] items = new String[] { "Foo", "Bar", "Fizz", "Bin"};
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter =
            new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.reminder_row, R.id.text1, items);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```