# How to implement filter search for listAdapter?

Tags: android, eclipse, search, filter

adapter.getFilter().filter(s);Hi i looked through and research alot on how to implement filter search and i still cant get mine working. Currently im using listadapter with hashmap to display listview. Now how do i use the listadapter to do search function? Below is my code:

```
private ListAdapter adapter;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> eventsList;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.homepage);
      searchBar.addTextChangedListener(filterTextWatcher);

// HashMap for ListView
eventsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
adapter = new SimpleAdapter(HomepageActivity.this, eventsList,
R.layout.list_event, new String[] { TAG_EID, TAG_ENAME, TAG_CNAME, TAG_CREATED_AT },
new int[] { R.id.eid, R.id.ename, R.id.cname, R.id.created_at });

// updating listView
setListAdapter(adapter);
}
private TextWatcher filterTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() { 

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) { 
    } 

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, 
            int after) { 
    } 

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, 
            int count) { 
        adapter.getFilter().filter(s);<--- THIS IS WHERE I GOT ERROR
    } 

}; 

@Override 
protected void onDestroy() { 
    super.onDestroy(); 
    searchBar.removeTextChangedListener(filterTextWatcher); 
}
```

Comment: is this helpful for you http://rakhi577.wordpress.com/2012/06/26/buttons-on-list-view-with-easy-searching-in-android/

Comment: try to use `afterTextChange` instead of `onTextChanged` for filtering Text from Adapter

Comment: Im using listadapter to help me display data to listview. I dont know how to change the listadapter to arrayAdapter where i can just use getFilter().filter(s) because this only provides for arrayAdapter.

Answer (score 0):

The Simple Short answer is you must extend `ListActivity` not `Actity`
as i faced the same problem and my hint reference was

[The method setListAdapter(ArrayAdapter) is undefined for the type ReminderListActivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10525881/android-for-dummies-code-error)